# Transitive closure in discrete-mathematics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I got confused when i came to a question where i was supposed to write    a transitive closure of $ R=\{<1,4>; <2,4>;<3,2>;<4,2>\}.$

$R$ is said to be transitive, if
 $(a, b) ∈ R$ and $(b, a) ∈ R ⇒ (a, c) ∈ R$

is it possible that by using the above form that the transitive closure could be $\{<1,2>;<2,3>;<3,4>;<4,3>\}$

Comment: You can't take away original elements!

Answer (score 0):

To make the transitive closure you keep all the elements you start with and add all those that are required to make the relation transitive.  You look for cases where you have both $\lt a,b\gt $ and $\lt b,c\gt $ and add $\lt a,c\gt $.  Then you look again in case you did that, had $\lt c,d\gt $ and now need to add $\lt a,d\gt $.  Keep going until you don't find any more.  Your answer fails because it lacks $\lt 1,4 \gt$ which is part of the original set and $\lt 1,3\gt$ which is required by two of your elements.